# Center collection while pinched

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am working on scrolling `UICollectionView` to the place where I have used pinch gesture. They are 2 ways I've figure out how could I do this :

The first one should be the best but it does not work indeed.

```
let pinchCenter = CGPoint(x: gesture.location(in: collectionView).x - collectionView.bounds.midX,
                                      y: gesture.location(in: collectionView).y - collectionView.bounds.midY)
            if let index = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: pinchCenter) {
                collectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
            }
```

What is doing, it is creating a `CGPoint` which is a placed exactly on the middle of the pinch gestures (two fingers), but there is no `IndexPath` in the `UICollectionView`, so it will not hit a `scrollToItem`.

Second option is to use only :

```
let center = gesture.location(ofTouch: 1, in: collectionView)
```

`ofTouch` If we point at 1, then the right finger will be taken, if 2 then left, still it's not that what I want, it is not a centered position of the `UICollectionView`.

Any ideas how could I improve the precision of second option or make the first working ?

**EDIT**

Third option is to calculate point using pattern for center in the line :

```
(x1+x2/2, y1+y2/2)
```

It is going to be :

```
let leftPinch = gesture.location(ofTouch: 1, in: collectionView)
            let rightPinch = gesture.location(ofTouch: 0, in: collectionView)

            let avg = CGPoint(x: (leftPinch.x + rightPinch.x) / 2, y: (leftPinch.y + rightPinch.y) / 2)
```

It is going to crash at `let leftPinch` with `NSInternalInconsistencyException`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there- I'm a bit confused reading your code. The pinchCenter parameter that you calculate is not the centre of the pinch but the location of the pinch relative to the centre of the collection view's bounds. This means that if the pinch is in the top left of the collection view you are going to get negative x and y coordinates so it's not surprising you're not hitting any cells. For your second option, why can't you just calculate the coordinate that lies mid-way between the location of the two touches? Thoughts welcome.

Comment: @Sparky Could u have a look at the edit ?

Comment: You need to remember that you are working with an array of touches: I believe the first touch (which is not necessarily the right one) is index 0, the second is index 1.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Do u have any other idea how could I handle that ?